# How to place Progress Bar inside viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-progressbar

I have to design below UI. I had placed progressbar and imageview inside a viewpager. Viewpager contains custom adapter which extends PagerAdapter. on first item my progress works fine but for second item am facing an issue that progress bar sets to zero always, Am used (https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) this custom circular progressbar or any new solution please.

Thanks in Advance.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6zSP.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do the same one :)
Take a loot at [Android Circular Music ProgressBar](https://github.com/aliab/circular-music-progressbar)

You layout will look like this:

```
<info.abdolahi.CircularMusicProgressBar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/album_art"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/maron5"
        app:border_color="#00796B"
        app:border_width="2dp"
        app:centercircle_diammterer="1"
        app:progress_color="#80CBC4"
        app:progress_startAngle="40"
    app:draw_anticlockwise="false" />
```

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: yes layout is same but facing issue on loading data in adapter. My progressbar in second list item of viewpager is issue. not able to restart that for 2nd item.

Comment: Post please, your code here or send me a link to email